# Typeahead drop down list is the same despite data from the source is updated JavaScript php

Tags: javascript, php, tags, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using Bootstar Tags-input: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

This is the HTML and script I use.

It shows tags, and I get typeahead. The file refers to tags.json file.

```
<br><input type="text" name="tags" id="tags" data-role="tagsinput" placeholder="tag1,tag2,tag3" required>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ rel }}js/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ rel }}typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    //Koden er kopiert og tilpasset fra https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/
    // Initializing the typeahead
    var tags = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: {
            url: 'tags.json',
            filter: function(list) {
                return $.map(list, function(tags) {
                    return { name: tags }; });
            }
        }
    });
    tags.initialize();

    $('#tags').tagsinput({
        trimValue: true,
        typeaheadjs: {
            name: 'tags',
            displayKey: 'name',
            valueKey: 'name',
            source: tags.ttAdapter()
        }
    });
</script>
```

Despite the contents of tags.json file is updated, the drop-down still is the same. (I do reload the page everytime, some commented I did not so it, I forgot to mention 
that).

I checked by searching to see if there's another tags.json file, but there's only one tags.json file in my project folder.

I deleted and tested with new file. When I change the filename from `url: 'tags.json',` it does work on the first time. It gets the contents of the .json file right. But after I change the contents of .json file, or even if I delete it, the drop-down still shows the same data (after page reload).

**How can I update the dropdown list from typeahead using Bootstrap Tags-input?**

Comment: So you're changing the content of the JSON file, then wanting the content of the dropdown to change without reloading the page?

Comment: `tags.json` is only fetched once per page load. If that file is changed afterwards, your dropdown won't update unless the page is reloaded. How often is `tags.json` updated? You may want to consider polling updates so that it's updated more frequently.

Comment: @Dave Chen I did reload the page several times but the result is same everytime.

Comment: Ah this sounds like a caching issue then. Can you try `url: 'tags.json?t=' + Math.random()` for the URL?

Comment: You can also put `tags.clearPrefetchCache();` before `tags.initialize();` and it should remove any caching of the tags.

Comment: @Dave Chen thank you very much, both method works. Method with adding query ('?t=' + Math.random()'  to .json file works faster. No need to reload page again with that when you visit the page.